# How should I output json from JSONArray using jax rs/jersey?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs

My restful API method looks like this

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONArray getMessage()
{
    FreeDriversService f=new FreeDriversService();
    try {
      return f.executeFreeDrivers(); // this method return a JSONArray
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return new JSONArray(); 
    }
}
```

When I use the `toString()` method on `JSONArray` it does produce a result, but I would like `JSON` as output. How can i do that?

I am getting this error

```
A message body writer for Java class org.json.JSONArray, and Java type class org.json.JSONArray, and MIME media type application/json
was not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Summary:-**

You have mentioned the output as `JSON` in the `@Produces` annotation as `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` but instead of sending `JSONObject` your method `getMessage` is returning `JSONArray`.
You can not convert a `JSON` to an `JSONArray` simply, because in `JSONArray` same type of `JSONObject` can be repeated multiple times with same `keys`, which can be replaced by the later `values` of the multiple `JSONObject`.

**Solution** :-

You can create a `JSONObject` and can put the `JSONArray` inside it as a `value` for a user defined `key`.

```
       @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getMessage(){
        JSONObject finalJson = new  JSONObject ();
        JSONArray inputArray = new JSONArray();
            FreeDriversService f=new FreeDriversService();
            try{

            inputArray = f.executeFreeDrivers(); // this method return a JSONArray
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());

            }
            finalJson.put("array",inputArray );
            return Response.status(200).entity(finalJson).build();
            }
```

Comment: What should be return type of getMessage? JSONObject as return type is giving same error

Comment: @NitinJaiman The return type should be `Response` object. From `JSONObject` you can construct `Response` object as `Response.status(200).entity(finalJson).build();` . Edited that in above code as well.